# LEFT JOIN return result for not equal ON

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT bm_events.name AS event_name,
       bm_events.uid AS event_uid,
       bm_events.organising,
       bm_organising_company.uid,
       bm_organising_company.name
FROM bm_events LEFT JOIN bm_organising_company
     ON bm_events.organising = bm_organising_company.uid
```

And here is the result

```
Acontraluz  68  66,90   66  Advanced Music S.L.
```

Column "bm_events.organising" is a varchar with comma separated values.

So as "bm_events.organising" is equal to "66,90" on bm_events table, I expect to have no result for bm_organising_company.uid, bm_organising_company.name.

Could you explain to me why I got the result of bm_organising_company.uid = 66 ?

Thanks :)

Comment: When you compare a string to an int in MySQL the string is converted to an int and then compared. "66,90" becomes 66 as an integer.

Comment: If you want to compare VARCHAR, you need to use `like` keyword instead of `=`.

Comment: So obvious. I was thinking it was a strict comparaison. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT e.name as event_name, e.uid as event_uid, e.organising, oc.uid, oc.name
from bm_events e left join
     bm_organising_company oc
     on e.organising = oc.uid
```

As mentioned in the comments, you have a comparison between a string and a number.  That is manifestation of your problem, and you can fix it using `find_in_set()`:

```
on find_in_set(oc.uid, e.organizing)
```

However, that is not the root of your problem.  The major cause of your problem is that you are storing lists of integers in a string.  Here are reasons why you don't want to do this:

- Values should be stored in the correct type, so a number should be stored as a number.
- Ids should have problem foreign key references.  You cannot do this with a string.
- The semantics of comparisons are confusing.
- SQL has correct data structures for lists.  They are called "tables".
- The resulting queries cannot take advantage of indexes, so they are not optimized.

So, you should have a table called something like `OrganizingUsers` with one row per "event" and per "user".  This is called a junction table and is the right way to represent lists in SQL.